# MySQL, how can I reference a subquery field in a SELECT query

Tags: mysql, correlated-subquery

I am trying to calculate account balances in MySQL using the following query

```
SELECT accountNumber,
(
    SELECT  amount
    FROM    accountDebits
    WHERE   accountNumber = accounts.accountNumber
) debits,
(
    SELECT  amount
    FROM    accountCredits 
    WHERE   accountNumber = accounts.accountNumber
) credits,
credits - debits as balance
FROM    accounts
```

But I get this error:

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'credits' in 'field list'

How can I refer to the subquery aliases in the select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap it with another subquery that does the calculation:

```
SELECT accountNumber, debits, credits, credits - debits as balance
FROM (
  SELECT accountNumber,
  (
    SELECT  amount
    FROM    accountDebits
    WHERE   accountNumber = accounts.accountNumber
  ) debits,
  (
    SELECT  amount
    FROM    accountCredits 
    WHERE   accountNumber = accounts.accountNumber
  ) credits
  FROM accounts
  ) x
```

While this gets your query up and running, you'd be better off with an outer join:

```
SELECT accountNumber, debits, credits, credits - debits as balance
FROM (
  SELECT
      a.accountNumber,
      coalesce(sum(d.amount), 0) debits,
      coalesce(sum(c.amount), 0) credits,
  FROM accounts a
  LEFT JOIN accountDebits d
    ON d.accountNumber = a.accountNumber
  LEFT JOIN accountCredits c
    ON c.accountNumber = a.accountNumber
) x
```

Comment: @AdrianP could there be multiple credits or debits for a single account?

Comment: Yes there can be multiple, I modified the query to use `SUM(amount)` instead of `amount` afterwards

Answer (score 0):

Use the table.field convention, should work

```
SELECT accountNumber,
(
    SELECT  amount
    FROM    accountDebits
    WHERE   accountNumber = accounts.accountNumber
) debits,
(
    SELECT  amount
    FROM    accountCredits 
    WHERE   accountNumber = accounts.accountNumber
) credits,
credits.amount - debits.amount as balance
FROM    accounts
```

Comment: That didnt work for me, I got this error: `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'credits.amount' in 'field list'`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do this:

```
SELECT a.*,
       (COALESCE(credits, 0) - COALESCE(debits, 0)) as balance
FROM (SELECT accountNumber,
             (SELECT SUM(ad.amount)
              FROM accountDebits ad
              WHERE ad.accountNumber = a.accountNumber
             ) as debits,
             (SELECT SUM(ac.amount)
              FROM accountCredits ac 
              WHERE ac.accountNumber = a.accountNumber
             ) credits
      FROM accounts a
     ) a;
```

You need the subquery because you cannot reference the derived columns in the same `SELECT` where they are defined.  You need the aggregation functions to combine all debits/credits into a single value for each account.